# I am able to access site from outside the server, cannot access local host or from servers internet browser

Tags: azure, iis

website hosted on IIS 10, server 2019 (VM on azure).
I've migrated form server 2012 and uninstalled AD.

I've looked for the last 5 hours on the web,
tried to change the port,
tried to alter DNS,
tried various browsers

Any thoughts will be appreciated.

Haim

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html Run a report so we might know what you are talking about.

Comment: provide more details to understand the issue;

Comment: Did you get any error messages?